# Output arbitrary tag element in Facelets?

Tags: jsf, facelets

I want to output a tag with dynamic attributes like:

```
<foo attr1="val1"
     attr2="val1"
     attr3="val1">
    Contents
</foo>
```

Where attribute names is unknown in compile time.

It's obviously c:forEach or ui:repeat doesn't work here:

```
<foo <c:forEach ... /> >
```

So, is there something like this?

```
<x:element name='foo'>
    <forEach>
        <x:attribute name='#{"attr" + index}'>
            #{"val" + index}
        </x:attribute>
    </forEach>
</x:element>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `f:attribute` (xmlns:f=http://java.sun.com/jsf/core), which would associates an attribute with the nearest parent UIComponent.

See:

- http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/j2ee/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/
- http://myfaces.apache.org/core11/myfaces-impl/tlddoc/f/attribute.html

Answer (score -1):

Try using xslt parsing for the existing xml feed. I think you can use  for this.
Please go through the xslt tutorial for more details.

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Comment: Sorry, it's nothing to do with xslt and xml feed.